# Show that for $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$ the central limit theorem holds.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $$P(X_n=n^{\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}=P(X_n=-n^\alpha),$$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that for $\alpha\ge-\frac{1}{2}$, the central limit theorem holds.

I understand that we have to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}\leq\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\, \mathrm{d}x$. But I don't know how to compute the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to compute this distribution or if this is not the correct way to approach this problem then tell me or give a hint about a possible way to approach this problem.

Comment: What formulation of CLT for variables with different distributions (and potentially growing variance, if $\alpha > 0$) do you use?

Comment: @mihaild It's the classical CLT. For a sequence of iid random variables $X_n$, with $\mathbb{V}X_1<\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mathbb{E}X_i}{\sqrt{n\mathbb{V}X_1}}\leq a\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\, \mathrm{d}x$, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But your $X_i$ are not identically distributed.

Comment: @mihalid Yes, you are right. I made a mistake. I guess we have to use the Lindeberg's/Lyapunov's version of the CLT. But I am having trouble to verify the Lindeberg's condition. Can you help me with it?